# A function to calculate cumulative maximum for a double matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function, matrix, max

Is there any function that can calculate cumulative maximum for a **double** matrix? I have a 1*3000 matrix and I need to calculate the cumulative maximum.
For example if the matrix is:

```
A = [8     3     6     7     9    10     6     2     2     3]
```

The cumulative maximum array will be:

```
B = [8     8     8     8     9    10    10    10    10    10]
```

I have tried **cummax** function but I faced this error:

Undefined function 'cummax' for input arguments of type 'double'

Comment: `cummax` is only in newer versions of Matlab, what version are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `cummax` isn't working then I came up with this little function

```
function m = cummax2(x)
    [X, ~] = meshgrid(x, ones(size(x)));
    %replace elements above diagonal with -inf
    X(logical(triu(ones(size(X)),1))) = -inf;
    %get cumulative maximum
    m = reshape(max(X'), size(x));
end
```

Comment: I tried this function you provided. I faced this error:  function cummax2(x)
 |
Error: Function definitions are not
permitted in this context.

Comment: You need to put it in a .m file.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative that uses `bsxfun`:

```
max(bsxfun(@(~,y)([A(1:y),-inf(1,numel(A)-y)]'), A', 1:numel(A)))
```